# How Do I Uninstall Google Voice Voicemail from an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, voicemail, google-voice

I installed Google Voice Voicemail on my wife's iPhone, thinking she would like it. You know, the thing where you put in the funky long set of numbers and dial somewhere, and kapoof, you now have Google Voice Voicemail instead of iPhone voicemail.

Now she tells me she doesn't like it, and wants to go back to the old Apple iPhone Voicemail. How do I revert this back?

Comment: You would think uninstalling the app would remove the call forwarding, I just had to same problem :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply turn off voicemail for calls to google voice using the web interface for that google voice number.

[image: voice settings]

If you activated the carrier settings like in the image below, click the instructions to reverse those changes with the carrier. You could also call your carrier for help since it's a feature that has different commands on a per-carrier basis. They will be most familiar with their settings and order to undo the change if Google doesn't help undo it.

[image]

Without your carrier forwarding all calls to Google, you can still keep Google Voice and have both voicemail systems separate.

That will simply forward the call and let the iPhone and carrier handle the voicemail.

Lastly, you don't have to delete the google app for this to work, but that might make things simpler if your wife doesn't want to call out using the Google Voice number anymore.